# Add data to existing dataframe based on condition in R

Tags: r, dataframe, csv, if-statement

I have a large number of csv file.(more than 500csv file)
Currently I have to extract the specific cells 1 by 1 csv manually.And make a new dataframe based on category.
Below is my code to import the data, create variable for every csv specific cells information and create a new dataframe.

```
#Import the csv and create a list
tempx <- list.files(pattern ="*.csv")
mylist <- lapply(tempx,read_csv)
```

Create variable one by one for extract specific data in every csv.file and delete the zero value

```
file1 <- mylist[[1]][132:167,4][apply(mylist[[1]][132:167,4], 1,
                                          function(row) all(row !=0 )), ] 


file2 <- mylist[[2][132:167,4][apply(mylist[[2][132:167,4], 1,
                                          function(row) all(row !=0 )), ] 

file3 <- mylist[[3]][132:167,4][apply(mylist[[3]][132:167,4], 1,
                                          function(row) all(row !=0 )), ]

file4 <- mylist[[3]][132:167,4][apply(mylist[[3]][132:167,4], 1,
                                          function(row) all(row !=0 )), ]

file5 <- mylist[[3]][132:167,4][apply(mylist[[3]][132:167,4], 1,
                                          function(row) all(row !=0 )), ]
```

Create a unequal length dataframe.

```
table <- qpcR:::cbind.na((file1,file3,file4,file5)
                                    

colnames(table) <- c("Name1" ,"Name2")

table1 <- as.data.frame(lapply(table ,as.numeric))
```

Above code is the one i can only do.Manually create those variable`file1` to `file500` and slot in  variable 1by1 to the `table` dataframe column based on the row17,column 4 of that csv file.
(example of file105: `my list[[105]][17,4]`.)

Is it possible to use `if else` or `case_when` to add row to `table1`(existing dataframe or create a new dataframe) based on
`mylist[[1]][17,4]` or [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZzzU.png)][17,4] until [[500]][17,4] etc.
(finally the dataframe will be  10+ Column for all the 500 csv file.)

Just like `if[[1]][17,4]="Name1"`, slot in the `[[1]][132:167,4]` without zero value to `table` column "Name1".

Image 1 and image 2  are the one csv.
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZzzU.png)
[Number 1 is the data i want to be a Columnname `mylist[[1]][17,4]`
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFwXO.png)
[Number 2 is the the data i want to be a row`mylist[[1]][132:167,4]` and  slot in to a correct column according `mylist[[1]][17,4]` without zero .`

Image 3 and image 4 are the one csv.
[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alH5T.png)&[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIQdZ.png)
[Number 3 & 4 will be another same example as number 1 and 2.

Comment: `filelist <- lapply(mylist, function(x) { x[132:167,4][apply(x[132:167,4], 1, function(row) all(row !=0 )), ] })` should work to create all the `file*` objects in a list. It might be a little cleaner to do `filelist <- lapply(mylist, function(x) { x[132:167,4][rowSums(x[132:167,4] == 0) == 0, ] })`, replacing the `apply` with a `rowSums`.

Comment: For help with your actual question, it would be really nice to have a copy/pasteable reproducible example with a little bit of sample data to illustrate. 2 or 3 small sample data frames should be plenty to illustrate the issue.

Comment: You can automate the creation of file1, file2, file3, etc. by creating these files in a loop.
First, create your outlist:
`outlist <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(files))`, then, filled it in:
`for (i in length(mylist)) {outlist[[i]] <- mylist[[i]][132:167,4][apply(mylist[[i]][132:167,4], 1, function(row) all(row !=0 )), ]}`.
Then, you can cbind the list: `table <- qpcR:::cbind.na((outlist)`. But it is hard to be sure it will work without a reproducible example.

Comment: Please check the last 2 sentences upload 4 image for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use loops for this.
I would usually use purrr here.
Hard to get it excatly right without a proper reproducible example.

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

table1 <- map(my_list, ~ .x [132:167,4][apply(mylist[[1]][132:167,4], 1,
                                          function(row) all(row !=0 )), ]) %>%
    qpcR:::cbind.na()%>%
    set_names(~c("Name1" ,"Name2"))%>%
    as.data.frame()%>%
    mutate(across(everything(), as.numeric))
```

Comment: Please check the last 2 sentences upload 4 image for your reference.